# What is Camel Route policy?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm studying Apache camel very first time.

To handle faults in a route, I saw below code snippet after a cFile component in cJavaDSLProcessor component.

```
.handleFault().routePolicy(15).threads(10).maxPoolSize(20)
```

May I know please what's happening here with low level description and the purpose behind that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.handleFault().routePolicy(15).threads(10).maxPoolSize(20)
```

`handleFault()` -. Error handlers and the onException clause in Camel only handle Exceptions. Faults thrown by endpoints are not handled by default. In order to enable errorHandlers and onExceptions clauses to manage exceptions the handleFault property must be set.

In case of Fault, what would be routePolicy is deterimed by

`routePolicy()` - is used to control route(s) at runtime. For example you can use it to determine whether a route should be running or not. However the policies can support any kind of use cases.

`threads(10)` - creates a thread pool profile for the route with core pool size as 10

`maxPoolSize()` - thread pool max Pool size would be 20.

some defaults will be there like 
`keepAliveTime` = 60 seconds
`maxQueueSize` = 1000

[Source](http://camel.apache.org/): Its always better to check the documentation for such questions.

Comment: thanks for sharing this info. I have googled alot to find handleFault() property so that I could see how its defined but no success. Secondly like you said "routePolicy() - is used to control route(s) at runtime. For example you can use it to determine whether a route should be running or not." So in my case case am using 15 as maxInflightExchanges, so Does it means that it will control the route to not to have more than 15 messages process at a time or something else ?